# xampp not working, just installed

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I just downloaded xampp from "https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html" this link, and switched off my defender as it asked me to, after instaling, i ran it and switched on mysql and clicked admin on the gui but i get this " The web page is not available ", even though mysql is stil higlighited green in the ui, i even tried localhost:3306 as my port is 3306 and my pid is 4584, but still got " the web page not available" am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: How do you access the website in the browser? Which url?

Comment: Is apache also running?

Comment: do you running skype? often there is a port conflict!

Comment: localhost default port is 8080, some cases skype and xampp enter in conflicts. if you are using skype try close it and start apache

Comment: can you please share your error message.

Comment: Apache is not running on please check it

Comment: If you are using skype,you can change skype port number.skype-->tools-->options-->connection-->port number

Comment: i tried both chrome and firefox, both of them show "Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured." this error, even though my mysql is running, @Rizier123, and no i am not using any other softwares while running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your server error logs under `<XAMPP_INSTALLATION_PATH>/apache/logs/` directory. It will guide you if any port is already occupied.

I agree with @ErasmoOliveira as most of the time I faced similar thing & exiting skype fixed this issue.

Comment: @Mahesh24 My sql is up running, simultaneously i tried turning apache on but i got this error in xampp "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
19:39:24  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
19:39:24  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
19:39:24  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
19:39:24  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
19:39:24  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
19:39:24  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums "

Comment: @user3463857, did u check apache error log under `<XAMPP_INSTALLATION_PATH>/apache/logs/`?

Comment: there arent any error files in the path, i just have a install.log file in that folder !

Comment: Try starting apache, you will surely get error.log in case you are not able to start that due to any error.

Answer (score 0):

run your XAMPP, then click Setup (Apache line), click on Apache (httpd.conf). in this file find the line `Listen 80`, change 80 with another port, example: type 81 or 8080 or whatever you want but that it respects the format `/^[8]{1}[\d]{1, 3}$/`

restart apache again, you will surely work correctly by tapping to your browser `http://localhost:81` (if you replaced the port to 81)

Comment: i tried that, i put it to port 81 only still not working. this is error when i try to switch on apache "Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
22:17:37  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
22:17:37  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
22:17:37  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
22:17:37  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
22:17:37  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
22:17:37  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums"

Comment: type this command on your command line : `netstat -abno`, it will display all the process and used ports. find what process is using the port 3306 or (80, 81). run services.msc after finding this process, and just kill it.

Comment: i just tried that but port 3306 is being used by mysqld.exe , so killing that doesent make sense right !